# If $f$ is an entire function, and $\Im(f)$ is bounded below then show $f$ is a constant function

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f$ is an entire function, and $\Im(f)$ is bounded below then show $f$ is a constant function.

The solutions write:

suppose $\Im(f(z)) \geq m$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$. Then consider the entire function $g(z) = if(z)$, then we have $$|e^{g(z)}| = |e^{if(z)}| = e^{-\Im(f(z))} \leq e^{-m}$$ then they conclude. My question is, could someone explain the step: $|e^{if(z)}| = e^{-\Im(f(z))} $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(z) = a + ib \implies if(z) = ai - b$

$$|e^{if(z)}| = |e^{ai}e^{-\Im f(z)}| = |e^{ai}| \cdot |e^{-\Im f(z)}| = |e^{-\Im f(z)}|$$

as $|e^{ai}| = 1$

---

Your solution uses Liouville theorem.

Another way would be to use [Picard's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem), since $f(z)$ misses infinite values of $\mathbb C$

Answer (score 0):

You have $f(z)=\mathcal {Re} f(z) + \mathbb i \space \mathcal {Im} f(z)$, therefore $\mathbb i f(z) = \mathbb i \space \mathcal {Re} f(z) - \mathcal {Im} f(z)$. Now, $|\mathbb e ^{\mathbb if(z)}| = |\mathbb e ^{\mathbb i \space \mathcal {Re} f(z) - \mathcal {Im} f(z)}| = |\mathbb e ^{\mathbb i \space \mathcal {Re} f(z)}| \cdot |\mathbb e ^{- \mathcal {Im} f(z)}| = \mathbb e ^{- \mathcal {Im} f(z)}$ because the exponential of an imaginary number has modulus $1$ and the exponential of a real number is positive.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that for $g(z)=f(z)-mi$, we have $\Im g\ge 0$, so
$$
\varphi(z)=\frac{g(z)-i}{g(z)+i}
$$
Is an entire function which is bounded, because $|\varphi(z)|\le1$ (why?) now apply Liouville's theorem.